# Laravel - do I need a service provider for each of my service containers / custom classes?

Tags: php, laravel, service, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Service containers / providers are probably much simpler concepts than I imagine, but after several hours of reading I still don't get it, entirely.

I have created a simple `DateFormat` class within `app/Library`. After creating an alias for it inside `\config\app.php` I can use it right away in any controllers or blade templates.

```
<?php namespace App\Library;

class DateFormat {

    public static function getDate($timestamp){
      // processing the timestamp      
    }

}
```

Did I just create a Service Container? If yes, do I need to create a Service Provider as well? Where come bindings into the picture?

I would really appreciate some light on the subject.
Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No. What you created is simply an alias to your class. Services Providers are a way of binding a specific class, and often are used in conjuction with a [Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/master/facades).

An alias is simply a convenient way to use a class without having to import the entire namespaced class every time.

For example, if you have a class `\My\Very\Long\Class\Adapter`, you could alias this in `config/app.php`:

```
// config/app.php
<?php
'aliases' => [
    // a bunch of aliases
    'MyAdapter' => My\Very\Long\Class\Adapter::class,
]
```

And now you can just do:

```
<?php

new MyAdapter();
...
```

instead of:

```
<?php

use My\Very\Long\Class\Adapter;
...
new Adapter();
...
```

A Service Provider is often used when you want to resolve a dependency, most commonly through injection. This can be helpful when the class you want to resolve requires parameters to passed into the constructor or has a common setup every time. You can perform all that setup in the Provider.

Here's a scenario:

You have an API that you want to interact with. We'll call it SuperApi. The docs for SuperAPI say that to create an instance of the SuperApi class, you have to do something like:

```
<?php
// Some method (a controller or something)
public function index()
{
    $superApi = new \SuperApi\Connector($key, $secret);
    return $superApi->getCustomers();
}
```

Now, every time you want to create an instance of this, you'll have to do the same setup (or abstract it to some class, but the fact remains that you need to pass a `$key` and `$secret` to the constructor).

If you were to create an alias for this `Connector` class, maybe it would be:

```
// config/app.php
<?php
'aliases' => [
    // a bunch of aliases
    'SuperApi' => SuperApi\Connector::class,
]
```

So with that alias, you can now do this:

```
<?php

// Some method (a controller or something)
public function index()
{
    $superApi = new SuperApi($key, $secret);
    return $superApi->getCustomers();
}
```

But you see, that even with the alias, you still need to pass the `$key` and `$secret`.

This is where a Service Provider can help.

```
// app/Providers/SuperApiProvider.php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use SuperApi\Connector;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SuperApiProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('superApiConnector', function ($app) {
            return new ApiConnector($app['config']->get('super-api.key'), $app['config']->get('super-api.secret'));
        });
    }
}

// app/Providers/SuperApi.php (the Facade)
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class SuperApi extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'superApiConnector';
    }
}


// config/super-api.config
<?php

return [
    'key' => env('SUPER_API_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('SUPER_API_SECRET'),
];

// config/app.php
<?php
'providers' => [
    // a bunch of providers
    App\Providers\SuperApiProvider::class,
]
```

See that the string you bind to in the provider (`'superApiConnector'`) is the same as what you return from the facade and the class name of the facade is how you'll actually call the binded class, in this case `SuperApi`.

Now, when you want to user the `SuperApi\Connector` class, you can do this:

```
<?php

// Some method (a controller or something)
public function index()
{
    return SuperApi::getCustomers();
}
```

And as I said above, where a provider really comes in handy is when you want to inject it and have [Laravel's IoC Container](https://laravel.com/docs/master/container) automatically resolve the injected class:

```
<?php
// Some method (a controller or something)
public function index(SuperApi $api)
{
    return $api->getCustomers();
}
```

To be clear, you do NOT need a Service Provider to take advantage of dependency injection. As long as the class can be resolved by the application it can be injected. That means whatever arguments the constructor of the class you're injecting takes need to also be auto-resolvable.

Comment: thanks, this is the answer I was seeking for an entire evening. Two more little questions: 1. Isn't it necessary to add `SuperApiProvider` to providers list in app.php to get injection working? 2. In the provider, could I theoretically replace the facade inside the binding to: `$this->app->bind('App\SuperApi\Connector', function ($app) {`?

Comment: Yes to your first question. I've added that to the answer. As far as your second question goes, You sure could pass the class path as the first argument and do away with the Facade. If you did this, then you need to import using the full class path when you inject. OR, you can create an alias and inject that. Either should get resolved correctly. If you choose to not use a Facade, then you can't do: `SuperApiConnector::getCustomers()` since (in my example) that method isn't actually static.

Comment: Thank you for the nicely elaborated answers, now all pieces came into place! Have a nice day! :)

Comment: @tptcat, let us look at this line `return new ApiConnector($app['config']->get('super-api.key'),`. 1) You get the auper api key from the `.env` file, right ? 2) Suppose  the user needs to use different keys at different times, how will you write the line then ?

Comment: @tptcat, inside `register()` method , you used `return new ApiConnector($app['....` - where do you get the `ApiConnector` class ?

Comment: @tptcat This did not answer my question, yet I'm upvoting it anyway because it's such a great response to the OP. Thanks for spending the time on answers like this.